# name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

I was doing a project in google collab. But I faced this error. What should I do ?? I am working with Gaussian Navie Bayes

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv
from sklearn import datasets

dataset = datasets.load_wine()`

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = dataset['data']
y = dataset['target']

x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(x , y , test_size = 0.25 , random_state = 42)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

se = StandardScaler()
x_train = se.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = se.fit_transform(x_test)

model1 = GaussianNB()
model1.fit(x_train , y_train)

y_pred = model1.predict(x_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test , y_pred)
print("The accuracy of the given data using gaussian naive bayes model is:-",accuracy)
```

[image]

**This is the code that I used. This was done in google collab. I have attached the error snipet too..**

Comment: `x` *isn't* defined, anywhere in the code you posted.  There's an `X`, but that's not the same variable name at all.

Comment: Capital X is defined but lowercase x is not. Just change to X instead of x

Answer (score 1):

Change x to X in the following line

```
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(X , y , test_size = 0.25 , random_state = 42)
```

since you mentioned X at

```
X = dataset['data']
```